# Laravel switch case

Tags: php, laravel

```
switch($catDiscount->second_status) { 
    case false:

       logger(4444444);

       foreach ($products as $product) {
         $product = Product::find($product->id);
         $product->discount_percent = $catDiscount->old_percent + $catDiscount->percent;
         $product->save();
       }
     break;

    case true:

       logger(66666666);
       foreach ($products as $product) {
         $product = Product::find($product->id);
         $product->discount_percent = $product->discount_percent + $catDiscount->percent;
         $product->save();
       }
        $catDiscount->second_status=false;
        $catDiscount->save();
       break;

      default :
   }
```

Problem is when updated second_status to false inside case true , on this time working case false , What I should do for update status and dont work till next request.

Answer (score 1):

```
function switchCase($catDiscount)
{
    switch($catDiscount->second_status) {
        case false:

            logger(4444444);

            foreach ($products as $product) {
                $product = Product::find($product->id);
                $product->discount_percent = $catDiscount->old_percent + $catDiscount->percent;
                $product->save();
            }
            break;

        case true:

            logger(66666666);
            foreach ($products as $product) {
                $product = Product::find($product->id);
                $product->discount_percent = $product->discount_percent + $catDiscount->percent;
                $product->save();
            }
            $catDiscount->second_status=false;
            $catDiscount->save();
            switchCase($catDiscount);
            break;

        default :
    }
}
```